# Eclipse hangs forever, thread dump says Main thread is sleeping

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running Eclipse 3.7.2 in Solaris 11 X86. It hangs randomly (every few hours or every few minutes). When it hangs, I do a thread dump and it suggests that `Main` thread is in timed wait state. Eclipse never wakes up from the sleep state and becomes unresponsive, I have to restart Eclipse to use it again.

Main thread is sleeping because of:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.dragDetect
```

Is there any known fix to this issue?

Edit:

OS

```
SunOS solaris 5.11 11.0 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

Full stack trace:

```
"main" prio=3 tid=0x080e8400 nid=0x1 waiting on condition [0x08045000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.dragDetect(Control.java:2204)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.dragDetect(Tree.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_button_press_event(Control.java:2791)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_button_press_event(Control.java:2759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_button_press_event(Composite.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.gtk_button_press_event(Tree.java:1871)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1731)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:3530)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4408)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8422)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=3 tid=0x08209c00 nid=0x2 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=3 tid=0x0825d000 nid=0x8 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 713
```

Comment: You duplicated in, please fix it.

Comment: Can you paste the entire thread dump somewhere?  eg, Pastebin

Comment: thanks, I have attached full stack trace

Comment: I don't have a solution, but at the very least you should file an Eclipse bug report.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your system clock is jumping around?

Eclipse's event loop uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to keep track of time, and `currentTimeMillis` isn't guaranteed to be monotonic (unlike `System.nanoTime()` would have been.)

```
long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout) {
    eventPtr = OS.gdk_event_get ();
    if (eventPtr != 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        try {Thread.sleep(50);} catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

If so, as a workaround you requested at " [Is there a way to interrupt a sleeping thread in a running JVM, without having access to the application's code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224077) ", you can easily use JBoss Byteman to create a rule set, which bails from the sleep loop after a set number of sleeps.

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo {

    public void test1() {
        long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500;
        int i = 0;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout) {
            System.out.println(i++);
            try {Thread.sleep(50);} catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }


    public static void main(final String ... args) throws Exception {
        new Foo().test1();
    }

}
```

sleeper.btm:

```
RULE counter
CLASS Foo
METHOD test1
AT ENTRY
IF TRUE
DO createCountDown($0, 5)
ENDRULE

RULE sleeper
CLASS Foo
METHOD test1
AT INVOKE Thread.sleep()
IF countDown($0)
DO RETURN
ENDRULE
```

Run with Byteman script:

```
$ ~/Downloads/byteman-download-2.1.0/bin/bmjava.sh -l ./sleeper.btm Foo
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Run normally:

```
$ java Foo 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: thank you a fellow Redditor... have some karma ;) I managed to solve the problem by using solaris 10 instead of solaris 11.. not a good solution but it works for me

Comment: Did you figure out whether the culprit was the clock, or some other GDK feature?

Comment: no... after using Solaris 11 on x86 for a few weeks, I noticed that its JRE is generally speaking very unstable, and the system does not run smoothly at all (random crashes too often), so I have fallen back to solaris 10